# Error: https://registry.npmjs.org/react: tunneling socket could not be established

Tags: reactjs

Help me getting out of this error:
When i run- npx create-react-app firebase-auth then it gave me following error
[image]

Comment: This has happened because your network connection has been ost while your react project was being created. Try this again when you have a good internet connection.

Comment: screenshots are not helpful, they don't show up on searches for other in the future: please copy and paste your code as text